# Visual Studio 2022 quick action from constructor parameter to auto field creation not adding space

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In VS 2022, when I press Ctrl + . on a constructor parameter and select "Create and assign field/property", the resulting code is missing spaces around the assignment operator = like this:

```
_logger=logger
```

It's not a big deal obviously but annoying to fix manually for unified formatting (defeats the purpose of quick action). Is there a setting somewhere that can fix this?

Comment: Which option are you referring to? I tried multiple constructor options and everything is working fine for me (VS 2022 17.0.1). Is this in context of a `.razor` file? That's the only buggy place I know. Note that `Ctrl K, Ctrl D` should do the trick nicely if it still happens for you.

Comment: Just regular C# .cs files. Nope Ctrl K Ctrl D does not add those spaces for me either.

Comment: It is very annoying. It start happen to me in regular cs files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid to reset all settings: this behavior is controlled by the following setting:

[image: Shows options dialog for setting]

It is set to *Ignore spaces around binary operators* by default; if you change this to *Insert space before and after binary operators* the space will be added.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset your Visual Studio settings:

> Tools => Import and Export Settings => Reset all settings

This will reset all your settings (you can create a backup in the process). After the reset, spaces will be back to normal.